# Como executo um código com o aplicativo fechado ou minimizado?

Tags: objective-c, mobile, xcode

Estou querendo executar código que mantem a tela sempre acesa, ele já funciona perfeitamente quando estou dentro do APP, porem, se minimizo ou fecho ele, para de funcionar.

OBS: Estou usando UIKit.framework

código que mantem a tela acesa:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];
```

De qual forma eu poderia seguir com ele ativo mesmo fechando ou minimizando o app?

Achei este projeto na internet:

https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer/tree/master/FreeStreamerMobile

Ele é um APP de rádio, quando toco a rádio e minimizo o APP, ela segue tocando. Quero algo assim, só que ao invés de um Streaming de rádio, quero executar o código mostrado acima.

Comment: Já tentou colocar esse código no método _applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application_ do seu AppDelegate? Isso irá forçar sempre que o aplicativo voltar, colocar o tempo de espera como desativado.

Comment: Obrigado Lucas, vou tentar desta forma e até amanha dou retorno se consegui ou não :)

Comment: @LucasEduardo , como desativo o tempo de espera?

Comment: Publiquei um exemplo na pergunta. Neste exemplo quando minimizo a aplicação, ela continua funcionando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe app rodando em background em iOS além de algumas exceções (música, gps, bluetooth, etc).

Consulte a documentação oficial para mais informações: [iOS - Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)